# Cannot get valgrind memcheck when using clion(mac os) + Docker container based on Toolchains

Tags: docker, ubuntu, valgrind, clion, macos-big-sur

all

I am using M1 macbook with Mac OS 15, since the valgrind has not supported OS big sur yet now, I have to debug my C/C++ codes in a Docker container.

Though the Compiling process is correct, it seems that I cannot get any output info when running a valgrind memcheck.

DockerFile for ubuntu 20:04:

```
# CLion remote docker environment (How to build docker container, run and stop it)
#
# Build and run:
#   docker build -t clion/remote-cpp-env:0.5 -f Dockerfile.remote-cpp-env .
#   docker run -d --cap-add sys_ptrace -p127.0.0.1:2222:22 --name clion_remote_env clion/remote-cpp-env:0.5
#   ssh-keygen -f "$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "[localhost]:2222"
#
# stop:
#   docker stop clion_remote_env
# 
# ssh credentials (test user):
#   user@password 

FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get update && apt-get -y install tzdata

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y ssh \
      build-essential \
      gcc \
      g++ \
      gdb \
      clang \
      make \
      ninja-build \
      cmake \
      autoconf \
      automake \
      locales-all \
      dos2unix \
      rsync \
      tar \
      python \
  && apt-get clean

RUN ( \
    echo 'LogLevel DEBUG2'; \
    echo 'PermitRootLogin yes'; \
    echo 'PasswordAuthentication yes'; \
    echo 'Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server'; \
  ) > /etc/ssh/sshd_config_test_clion \
  && mkdir /run/sshd

RUN useradd -m user \
  && yes password | passwd user

RUN usermod -s /bin/bash user

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-e", "-f", "/etc/ssh/sshd_config_test_clion"]
```

I manually install valgrind via `apt install valgrind`

Then configure a new Clion toolchain as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1GcN.png)

And configure valgrind as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhJGh.png)

However when I try to run a valgrind memcheck, the valgrind output on Clion is empty
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6DfP.png)

Anyone who can give some help?

Comment: Can you run Valgrind from a shell?

Comment: @ Paul Floyd No doubt yes, but manually compiling seems not a good idea since the project is huge now... I need to do many unit tests instead of a whole project test, so urgent to find a way to run valgrind memcheck on my M1 MacBook

Comment: Can you just check that Valgrind works with some simple executable like `ps`? There's little to no activity on macOS in the official valgrind git repo. I have occasionally fixed regression test build issues but that it about all.

Comment: @Paul Floyd Thanks for the idea, I'll check if valgrind can work correctly in Docker container, but I have no idea how to monitor if valgrind is active when Clion send a request from mac os to the Docker container

Comment: Never used Docker. But finding out if you can run Valgrind in a shell will tell you the problem is not on the Valgrind end.